# What is this succulent with a tall flower spike with green pods in the UK?

Tags: identification, succulents

[image]

[image]

I saw this plant in the entrance to the Princess of Wales conservatory in [Kew Gardens](https://www.kew.org/kew-gardens/attractions/princess-of-wales-conservatory) yesterday, but couldn't see a name tag for it. Does anyone know what it is? It had a very tall flower spike with green pods on and the leaves were grassy and clumping. It was with the cacti and succulents.

Comment: Hi Rach. I've never been to that garden, although I just looked it up and it's gorgeous!! I'm having trouble understanding how the second picture fits in with the first. Is the spike growing sideways out of the dark part in the first picture? Also, did you see any purple flowers on that plant? The spike kind of looks like purple flowers which have gone to seed. Unfortunately, I'm not the expert here, but some clarification might be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Talk about a great picture showing spider mite!!!!  Ugh.  I'd be talking to the conservatory telling them they've got a problem!

Comment: Yes Sue the gardens are indeed gorgeous there. I especially loved the Princess of Wales conservatory and the palm house. The first photo is probably confusing because it is upside down. I've tried to change it but it keeps flipping it each time.

Comment: And well spotted with the spider mite Stormy! Pretty gross!!

Comment: @stormy - I'm puzzled - what makes you think this plant has a spider mite infestation?

Comment: That webbing could be for baby spiders I suppose if it were spring over there. But that is what I look for when I don't have my loop with me.

Comment: Posting pictures here can be kind of crazy. Weird things sometimes happen! I rotated the first picture. Is that how it's supposed to go? Feel free to tell me if it's still wrong, or what direction you need it to be in, and I'll do it again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a Yucca variety, possibly Yucca angustissima var.toftiae, though the leaves in your image look a fraction broader than they should be, so maybe a close relative. It has these curly filaments and narrow grass like leaves, which only make a relatively small clump at the base, but the flower stalk is anything up to 7 feet tall - the green seed pods are fairly typical of many Yucca varieties. Like most Yuccas, it forms clumps over time. Next to impossible to find a good photo of it, never mind one in flower, nor much detailed information, but there is an image of the basal leaf growth [here](https://www.stoneycreekcacti.net/yuccas.html).

Yucca filamentosa is much more commonly seen, which produces a fairly impressive flower spike, but I doubt Kew would feature anything quite so commonplace; its leaves are quite a bit broader and usually longer than the ones in your photo.

Comment: I had a feeling it was some kind of yucca. It does seem to fit well with the angustissima with the curly filaments, small clumping grass like leaves and huge flower stalk so I will mark this answer as correct unless anyone knows any different. Thank you

Comment: By the way, I see no evidence of spider mite - if this plant was exposed to outdoor air at the entrance to the House, then it definitely won't be any kind of spider mite - here in the UK, that only happens on indoor plants. Not quite sure why someone thought it might have spider mite really...

Comment: I believe you might be right about the yucca, Bamboo.  But I am puzzled why being exposed to outdoor air at the entrance would be a definite reason to not have spider mite?  This looks like it is indeed an 'indoor' plant?  I used to live in your very same latitude and spider mite were out of doors everywhere, especially under eaves. 'Someone'?  Grins...

Comment: @Rach I agree as well, Yucca...those curly hairs on the leaves I've never seen on Carex either.  Good instincts!

Comment: @stormy spider mites on plants outdoors in the UK are rare as hen's teeth -the only time you might see them is if its been extremely hot for a long time, usually in the south east,but its never usually hot enough for long enough here - changeable  maritime climate after all. Primarily a problem in glasshouses and houseplants here

Comment: Is a conservatory not a glasshouse?  I have lived in maritime influenced climates as well; primarily the Pacific Northwest. Isn't that the same as London?  I need GLOBE I forget to look up stuff on the internet.  I'll go look up our latitudes.  Hen's teeth...that is a rare saying but I have always loved it.  Tits on a snake, too...grins.

Comment: @stormy yes a conservatory is a glasshouse - but this plant is 'at the entrance' which might mean its just outside - that plant is hardy here, so it could be outside, its not clear from the question. But why do you think its got spider mite, what are you seeing that I'm not?

Comment: The picture of the flower/seed spike poking out to the side?  Put your glasses on.  I took mine off and I can't see the webbing, but the webbing is very clear, back lit. Ha ha how many times have I asked the same question of you!? Diagnosing plants and landscapes via pictures is the pits.  I'm getting better little by little, sigh.

Comment: @stormy Oh you mean that spiders web at the top? Not spider mite, there are spiders webs absolutely everywhere at this time of year - when I go gardening, I have stick to hand to clear them out of the way before venturing between plants. I needed  a stick to clear them off my balcony two days ago - all over the plants and between the seats and railings, the door/windows and floor, small, large ones, tiny ones, strands and webs everywhere. For iD, I just  googled plant with stiff, grass like leaves with curly filaments, selected images, and found it about halfway down - simples! U use yahoo tho